# Tracking the Madrid Interbank Offered Rate (MIBOR) and the Euro Interbank Offered Rate (EURIBOR)

Tags: interest-rate

Does anybody know how to quickly check (or track) the EURIBOR and MIBOR? I tried Google Finance, but it doesn't recognize the acronyms or the names of the rates.

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find both here: http://www.bde.es/tipos/tipose.htm

Comment: That link now 404s!

Answer (score 1):

[For Euribor](http://www.euribor.org/)

Nothing seems to exist for MIBOR, except maybe the [Spanish stock exchange.](http://www.bolsamadrid.es/ing/portada.htm)